# color of option in Angular select

Tags: angularjs, colors, ng-options, angularjs-select

How do I assign a font colour for each option in the dropdown menu in angular?

I tried to do it by adding 
`ng-style="{color:{{selectedCar.dropdown_color}};}"` to the select tag, but it's not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.cars = {
        car01 : {brand : "Ford", model : "Mustang", dropdown_color : "red"},
        car02 : {brand : "Fiat", model : "500", dropdown_color : "green"},
        car03 : {brand : "Volvo", model : "XC90", dropdown_color : "blue"}
    }
});
</script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<p>Select a car:</p>

<select ng-model="selectedCar" ng-options="y.brand for (x, y) in cars"
        ng-style="{color:{{selectedCar.dropdown_color}};">
</select>

<h1>You selected: {{selectedCar.brand}}</h1>
<h2>Model: {{selectedCar.model}}</h2>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What error message did it get?

Comment: **Eliminate any issues that aren't relevant to the problem.** If your question isn’t about a compiler error, ensure that there are no compile-time errors.

Comment: I don't see an error message. https://jsfiddle.net/kqt4w821/ It seems to work just fine, it just doesn't show the coloured text in th dropdown menu

Comment: What about `angular.js:9101 Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token ';' not a primary expression at column 8 of the expression [{color:;}] starting at [;}].`???

Answer (score 0):

The `ngStyle` directive take an AngularJS expression.

So you have to write `ng-style="{color:selectedCar.dropdown_color}"`.
But it will change the text color of all the options to be the one of the selected cars.

If you want to have each option in the color defined in the attribute `dropdown_color`, you will have to use `ngRepeat` instead and change your select from

```
<select ng-model="selectedOption" 
        ng-options="y.brand for (x, y) in cars" 
        ng-style="{color : selectedCar.dropdown_color}">
</select>
```

to be

```
<select ng-model="selectedCar" 
        ng-change="selectedCar = cars[selectedOption]" 
        ng-style="{color : selectedCar.dropdown_color}">
   <option ng-repeat="(key, value) in cars" 
           ng-style="{color: value.dropdown_color}" 
           ng-value="key" 
           ng-bind="value.brand"></option>
</select>
```